# How do I add an option to change the width of the heat map in this script?

Tags: bash

I would like to add an option to change the width of the heat map that this script generates. Where would I put this in this script?

```
echo
echo "Please enter the directory you would like the heatmap in: "
read directory

echo ${#mutants[@]}

matrix_string=
heatmap_string=

if [[ ${num_controls} -gt ${num_mutants} ]]
then
        for i in "${!controls[@]}"
        do

            matrix_string="${matrix_string} ${controls[$i]}"
            heatmap_string="${heatmap_string} ${modification}_ctrl"
            if [[ i -lt ${#mutants[@]} ]]
            then
                    matrix_string="${matrix_string} ${mutants[$i]}"
                    heatmap_string="${heatmap_string} ${modification}_mut"
            fi
    done
else
    for i in "${!mutants[@]}"
    do
            if [[ i -lt ${#controls[@]} ]]
            then
                    matrix_string="${matrix_string} ${controls[$i]}"
                    heatmap_string="${heatmap_string} ${modification}_ctrl"
            fi
            matrix_string="${matrix_string} ${mutants[$i]}"
            heatmap_string="${heatmap_string} ${modification}_mut"
    done
fi

echo "creating matrix: computeMatrix reference-point --referencePoint center -R ${bedFile} -S${matrix_string} -a 1500 -b 1500 -o ${directory}matrix_${modification}.gz --missingDataAsZero"

computeMatrix reference-point --referencePoint center -R ${bedFile} -S ${matrix_string} -a 2000 -b 2000 -o ${directory}matrix_${modification}.gz --missingDataAsZero

echo "plotting heatmap: plotHeatmap -m ${directory}matrix_${modification}.gz --samplesLabel ${heatmap_string} -out ${directory}${modification}.png"

plotHeatmap -m ${directory}matrix_${modification}.gz --heatmapHeight 16 --samplesLabel ${heatmap_string} -out ${directory}${modification}.png
```

I haven't tried anything yet. This script was written by someone else.

Comment: you would duplicate the prompt at the top for `read directory` and add prompts and `read sizeW` and `read sizeH` (or how ever you want to name the variables.) Read and understand the code well enough to know how to validate the inputs and WHERE they belong in the script. (Possibly the `computeMatrix` and almost certainly the `plotHeatMap` calls at the end. Good luck!